# Problems while starting out with ROS - robotino_node launch issues

Tags: ros, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

While trying out this tutorial http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/Robotino_slam, I am not able to run the code roslaunch robotino_node robotino_node.launch hostname:=<insert your robotino's ip address here>, which gives me an error:

[robotino_node.launch] is neither a launch file in package [robotino_node] nor is [robotino_node] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Anyone can help me here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199518/problems-while-starting-out-with-ros---robotino_node-launch-issues/) by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved here: http://answers.ros.org/question/200083/problems-with-robotino_node-when-using-roslaunch/

---

Originally posted by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) with karma: 46 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0